# Custom ConstraintValidator for list validating

Tags: validation, spring-boot

Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE, javax.validation 2.0.1.Final are used.

I need to validate a request coming in into a controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/quotas/")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class QuotasController {

    private QuotasService quotasService;

    @ApiOperation("Post quotas")
    @PostMapping(value = "/quotas", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void quotas(@Valid @RequestBody List<Quota> quotaList){
        quotasService.insertQuotas(quotaList);
    }
}
```

Which calls a service:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class QuotasService {
    private QuotasRepository quotasRepository;

    public void insertQuotas(List<Quota> quotaList) {
        quotasRepository.saveAll(quotaList);
    }
}
```

Which saves the objects into MongoRepository method `<S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> var1)`.

Also I have a custom annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = 
SumOfValuesEqualsToOneHundredValidator.class)
public @interface SumOfValuesEqualsToOneHundred {
    String message() default "Sum of fields doesn't equal to 100";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Which is validated by:

```
public class SumOfValuesEqualsToOneHundredValidator implements 
ConstraintValidator<SumOfValuesEqualsToOneHundred, List<QuotaPayment>> 
{
    @Override
    public void initialize(SumOfValuesEqualsToOneHundred sumOfValuesEqualsToOneHundred) {
        //nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<QuotaPayment> quotaPaymentList, 
    ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
         return quotaPaymentList
                .stream()
                .mapToDouble(QuotaPayment::getValue)
                .sum() == 100;
    }
}
```

My aim is to validate DTO:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Quota {
    @Id
    private Integer storeId;
    @JsonProperty("quotas")
    private List<QuotaDelivery> quotaDeliveryList;
}
```

Specifically QuotaDelivery objects inside:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QuotaDelivery {
    QuotaDeliveryTypeEnum type;
    @JsonProperty("quotasForPaymentTypes")
    @SumOfValuesEqualsToOneHundred
    List<QuotaPayment> quotaPaymentList;
}
```

Against equality of sum of `QuotaPayments`' `value`s to 100.

Another words, only those `Quota` objects are valid, whose values from `QuotaDelivery` from `QuotaPayment` give 100 in total.

The problem is forementioned `SumOfValuesEqualsToOneHundredValidator` is been ignored. I mean debug mode shows that control never executes `public boolean isValid(List<QuotaPayment> quotaPaymentList, ConstraintValidatorContext context)` method.

What did I miss?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @Valid inside list and @Validated in controller class:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/quotas/")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Validated
public class QuotasController {

private QuotasService quotasService;

@ApiOperation("Post quotas")
@PostMapping(value = "/quotas", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void quotas(@Valid @RequestBody List<Quota> quotaList){
    quotasService.insertQuotas(quotaList);
}
```

}

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Quota {
    @Id
    private Integer storeId;
    @JsonProperty("quotas")
    private List< @Valid QuotaDelivery> quotaDeliveryList;
}

List< @Valid QuotaPayment> quotaPaymentList;
```

Comment: use @Valid before QuotaPayment

Comment: No effect unfortunately

Comment: i think u missing @Valid where u used list

Comment: Let me do a double check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176418/discussion-between-evgeny-mamaev-and-sajib).

Comment: use @Validated before controller

Comment: Yes, It worked after adding @Validated before Controller class signature.